# Merge node with same property value in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

When I search for nodes with a certain zipcode:

```
MATCH (z:ZipCode) WHERE z.zipcode = "2014 AAE" RETURN z.zipcode
```

I get duplicates:

```
z.zipcode
2014 AAE
2014 AAE
```

When I search for relations of a certain zipcode:

```
MATCH p=(z:ZipCode)-->() WHERE z.zipcode = "2014 AAE" RETURN p
```

I get a single zipcode node `2014 AAE` pointing to a house node `518Q`

How can I merge the zipcode nodes with the same property value,
but leave all the relations intact of the zipcode?

**Edit:**

After cybersam's answer I constructed a query. Is this the way to combine the nodes with APOC?

```
MATCH (z1:ZipCode)-->(), (z2:ZipCode)-->()
WHERE z1.zipcode = z2.zipcode
AND ID(z1) <> ID(z2)
WITH COLLECT([z1,z2]) AS zs
CALL apoc.refactor.mergeNodes(zs) YIELD node
RETURN node;
```

I get this as error:

```
Type mismatch: expected Collection<Node> but was Collection<Collection<Node>> (line 5, column 31 (offset: 160))
"CALL apoc.refactor.mergeNodes(zs) YIELD node"
```

Comment: I think it is not possible to get 2 results from first query and 1 from second. First query says clearly that there are 2 nodes with particular `ZipCode`. Is it possible that there is also some node `p` with zipcode `2014 AAE` which has `"IN-relation"`? I mean `(z:ZipCode)<--()`. Try to rewrite your second query to check it. But It is long time that I played with neo4j so maybe my thoughts are wrong.

Comment: If you want to remove duplicates you just have to match all nodes (matching 2 nodes e.g. `m` and `n`), compare them so you know they are same (have same properties `m.zipcode = n.zipcode`) but they are not same one node `m<>n`, than you have to find all relationships of `n` which are not in `m`, create these "n-relationships" on node `m` and finally delete `node n and all it's relationships`. Better solution would be make a good create queries so you merge duplicates during creating nodes and relationships and you don't have to do it later.

Comment: @Gondi: There are 2 zip code nodes, and only one of those is involved in a relationship. So, the results from the 2 queries make perfect sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[UPDATED]

*Aside: You have 2 nodes with the same zip code, but only one of those nodes has a relationship. This explains your results thus far.*

In neo4j 3.x, you can install the [APOC plugin](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures) and use the `mergeNodes()` procedure, which takes a collection of nodes. It merges the properties and relationships of the 2nd through last nodes onto the first node, and deletes the 2nd through last nodes.

For example:

```
MATCH (z:ZipCode)
WHERE z.zipcode = "2014 AAE"
WITH COLLECT(z) AS zs
CALL apoc.refactor.mergeNodes(zs) YIELD node
RETURN node;
```

Comment: What does `YIELD node` mean? That APOC converts it into a single node? I mean are their also other YIELD types?

Comment: The `mergeNodes` procedure returns (`YIELD`s) the first node from the collection. See the [Cypher refcard](http://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-refcard/current/) for more info on `CALL` and `YIELD`.

Comment: I edited my question based on your APOC suggestion CyberSam.

Comment: You should use my example query instead. Your added query is creating and trying to pass a collection of a collection. Also, you already know that only a single node has the relationship, so what you are attempting to do would not work anyway.